# React's Ref value not updating on change

Tags: reactjs, react-ref

I'm trying to set the disabled property of my button based on a condition of whether or not an input field is empty. However, the ref doesn't update the value which keeps the button disabled even when typing into the input. How could I make the ref update the value so the condition updates as well?

```js
// imports 
export default function Card() {
  const fields = useRef<{ [key: string]: { [key: string]: HTMLInputElement } }>({});
  return (
     //Rest of table
      <td className="flex-wrap px-2 text-sm text-gray-500">
        {/* Weight input */}
        <input
          type="number"
          inputMode="decimal"
          className="w-12 pl-1 text-base rounded-sm bg-gravel-100"
          ref={(el) => {
            if (!fields.current[section.id]) fields.current[section.id] = {};
            fields.current[section.id][exercise.name] = el as HTMLInputElement;
          }}
        />
      </td>
      <td>
        <button
          id={idx.toString()}
    {/* This condition doesn't change */}
          disabled={
            (loading && section.id + exercise.name === loadingExercise) ||
            fields.current[section.id][exercise.name].value === ""
          }
          onClick={() => {
            if (
              typeof fields.current[section.id][exercise.name].valueAsNumber ===
              "number"
            ) {
              setWeightInDb(
                section.name,
                exercise.name,
                fields.current[section.id][exercise.name].valueAsNumber
              );
              setLoadingExercise(section.id + exercise.name);
            }
            fields.current[section.id][exercise.name].value = "";
            console.log(
              "Field value" + fields.current[section.id][exercise.name].value
            );
          }}
          type="button"
          className="flex items-center justify-center w-8 h-8 border border-transparent rounded shadow-md disabled:shadow-none disabled:opacity-25"
        >
          {section.id + exercise.name === loadingExercise && loading ? (
            (console.log(exercise.name, loadingExercise),
            (<Spinner height={20} width={20} />))
          ) : (
            <CheckIcon className="w-6 h-6 p-1 text-center text-nomad-700" />
          )}
          {/* <LoadingSpring loading={false} /> */}
        </button>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you provide a state variable to the disabled prop inside the button. That way, the button is re-rendered, when the state variable changes.

```
import { useState } from "react";

const [isButtonDisabled, setIsButtonDisabled] = useState(false);

<button disabled={isButtonDisabled}>This is a Button</button>
```

Now implement a method, where you check whatever conditions you like. You could also use an useEffect to update the state variable when certain variables or props change, like so:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

useEffect(() => {
  if (someProp === true) {
    setIsButtonDisabled(true);
  } else {
    setIsButtonDisabled(false); 
  }
}, [someProp]);
```

As soon as you change the state, the button is going to re-render and shows up disabled, or not.

```
e.g.
setIsButtonDisabled(true);
```

Comment: I’m afraid that’s not really an option for me, as the button and input are return by a .map()